# Ungrouping separate processes with the same name from the taskbar

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell

I'm using Gnome Shell with the Dash To Dock extension, but Ubuntu Unity has the same issue:

I use firefox as my main browser and want to use the firefox developer edition for, well, developing.

But even though these 2 use separate binaries their windows are grouped in the taskbar.

This is so incredibly annoying, is there a way to turn this off and only group by binary location?

Answer (score 1):

I had to manually override the X11 `WM_CLASS`, which you can do as an argument to the firefox binary:

```
/opt/firefox-developer/firefox --class=firefoxdev
```

I  just added this to the `.desktop` entry and now I have a separate firefox taskbar entry.